# How to serialize a class containing a collection of an abstract class?

Tags: flutter, serialization, json-serialization

Lets take a look at a simple class hierarchy consisting of three classes:

1. An abstract base class:

   ```
   abstract class BaseClass {
     String name;

     BaseClass(this.name);
   }
   ```
2. A few classes derived from the abstract base class.

   ```
   @JsonSerializable()
   class ConcreteClass extends BaseClass {
     int someValue;

     ConcreteClass(this.someValue, String name) : super(name);

     factory ConcreteClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ConcretClassFromJson(json);

     Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ConcreteClassToJson(this);
   }
   ```
3. And finally a main class that stores all the concrete classes in a collection. Here's an example how it could look like:

   ```
   @JsonSerializable()
   class DataJuggler {
     Set<BaseClass> allTheDataInTheWorld = Set<BaseClass>();

     DataJuggler();

     factory DataJuggler.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$DataJugglerFromJson(json);

     Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$DataJugglerToJson(this);
   }
   ```

When launching the `build_runner` to generate the json serialization code, it fails with:

```
[SEVERE] json_serializable:json_serializable on lib/what_an_awesome_app/data_juggler.dart:

Could not generate `fromJson` code for `allTheDataInTheWorld` because of type `BaseClass`.
package:/totally_awesome/what_an_awesome_app/data_juggler.dart:12:25
   ╷
12 │   Set<BaseClass> allTheDataInTheWorld = Set<BaseClass>();
   ╵
```

Now the question is, what's wrong here? Or better: How can you get the json serialization code generated for the `DataJuggler` class? Your advise is very much welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to manually write down a bit of boilerplate code: https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/145, https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/371, and [Extend with fromJson in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676889/extend-with-fromjson-in-dart).

Notice that your BaseClass is lacking a `fromJson` currently, so DataJuggler definitely has no way of generating a `fromJson`!